# When I upload media, the "Saved" button isn't clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, save

In widget development when i upload an image, uploaded image is appeared but I can't click the "Saved" button because it is disabled.

Here is my "functions.php" code:

```php
public function widget($args, $instance){
  $man=$instance['mango'];
  $mo='<img src="'.$man.'" alt="" />';
  echo $args['before_widget'].$args['before_title'].$mo.$args['after_title'].$args['after_widget'];
}

public function form($instance){ 
  $man=$instance['mango'];
```

Create button:

```
<button class="button button-secondary"
        id="author_info_image">Upload Image</button>
```

Create hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" class="image_er_link"
       name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('mango'); ?>"
       value="<?php echo $man; ?>">
```

Create  tag to show image to dashboard:

```html
<div class="">
  <img src="<?php echo $man; ?>" width="250px" height="auto" alt="" />
</div>
```

Here is the "admin_script.js" code:

```js
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#author_info_image").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var imageUploader = wp.media({
        title: "Author Image Upload",
        button: {
          text: "Set up image",
        },
        multiple: false,
      });

      imageUploader.open();

      imageUploader.on("select", function () {
        var attachm =
            imageUploader.state().get("selection").first().toJSON();

        var lin = attachm.url;

        $("input.image_er_link").val(lin);

        $("img").attr("src", lin);
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a picture showing the disabled "Saved" button:

[image: In image save button cannot clickable]

Comment: What is this "save button"? You have provided no code that contains it.

Comment: Above the save button pic link is given.

Comment: An image does not help diagnose the problem. Please provide the code that displays and modifies the "Saved" button.

Comment: Sorry,there is no code,it is wordpress default function.In widget development when i upload an image,then i cannot click that save button because it is already remain saved.So how  will i save the upload image?

Comment: I suspect you can't click the "Saved" button, because it's not an action button. It's only and indicator to show the image has been uploaded (or at least chosen for upload). See [Using the Wordpress Media Uploader](https://dobsondev.com/2015/01/23/using-the-wordpress-media-uploader/).